# Not able to disable the select tag in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a variable

> createMode = true;

now in input tags

```
<input type="text" required="required" [disabled]='createMode'>
```

disable is working and the input is getting disabled.

Now, when i try the same with select tag it is not working

```
<select required [disabled]='createMode'>
<option selected="selected" > Mango</option>
</select>
```

can anyone please suggest how to make this select postion disabled as per the value of createMode

Comment: What happens if you put selected inside brackets?

Comment: nothing is happening

Comment: Can't reproduce https://plnkr.co/edit/FxMkw1oR9wTPthwxhPES?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

To have the `<options>` element selected when `createMode=true` you could do the following:

```
<options [attr.selected]="createMode ? true : null">
```

When `null` it will disappear completely, which it should.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options :
1)**you can use *ngif**

```
<select required *ngIf="!variable">
<option selected="selected" > Mango</option>
</select>
```

Where your variable is the one you use to toggle the select, putting ! to the expression you obtain the same effect of ng-hide.
2) **you can use [hidden] and bind it to the model**

```
<select required [hidden]='{{BooleanVariable}}'>
<option selected="selected" > Mango</option>
</select>
```